# Use logical operator as combine closure in reduce

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, closures, logical-operators

I am trying to reduce an array of `Bool`s by applying the logical operator **OR** (`||`) using the following code, however I get an error:

```
func reduceBools(values: [Bool]) -> Bool {
    return values.reduce(false, combine: ||)
}
```

> Ambiguous reference to member '||'

Analogously for integers the code works like a charm.

```
func reduceInts(values: [Int]) -> Int {
    return values.reduce(0, combine: +)
}
```

I was able to make it work by adding a `||` function (code below) or using a `{ $0 || $1 }` closure but I dislike these approaches and I would prefer simply passing the operator.

```
func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs || rhs
}
```

The same thing happens for the logical **AND** (`&&`) operator.

How can I make it work without using the hack above?

Comment: That seems to be a bug/restriction due to the "autoclosure" parameters of `||` and `&&`. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648268/what-is-the-type-of-the-logical-operators and the following comments.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link! i was thinking, that i am just a stupid man ...

Comment: @MartinR that seems to be the case :/ Is there any rdar on it so I can dupe it?

Comment: @fpg1503: None that I know of.

Comment: I've opened a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1793)

Answer (score 43):

As an alternative, you could use the following approach

```
// ||
func reduceBoolsOr(values: [Bool]) -> Bool {
    return values.contains(true)
}

// &&
func reduceBoolsAnd(values: [Bool]) -> Bool {
    return !values.contains(false)
}
```

Note that `.reduce` [comes with an overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750636/swift-performance-map-and-reduce-vs-for-loops/33752119). If the *end result* is the importance of your question (rather than enquiring above the unexpected behaviour of `||` and `&&` operators in this context), then perhaps the pragmatic approach above can be of help, even if it doesn't really reduce the array, however producing the same result due to the simple nature of the boolean type.

Comment: I'd argue that using contains is even better in this case, because you're describing the result you want to get, rather than how to calculate it. It's even more declarative than the usual functional approach. :)

Answer (score 14):

### Swift 4.2+ / Xcode 10.0+

In modern versions of `Swift` there is [allSatisfy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy#parameters) function, which checks all elements for satisfying some rule.

---

In OP's case:

```
values.allSatisfy { $0 }
```

---

**UPD:**

To make this work for OR, do

```
!values.allSatisfy{!$0}
```

Thanks to [Andy Weinstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826946/andy-weinstein)

Comment: To make this work for OR, do !values.allSatisfy{!$0}

Answer (score 8):

Following approach will work

```
values.reduce(false) { $0 || $1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ambiguous reference to member '||' means, that there are more than one possible candidates, from which compiler is not able to choose. In your case those are

```
public func ||<T : BooleanType, U : BooleanType>(lhs: T, @autoclosure rhs: () throws -> U) rethrows -> Bool
```

and

```
public func ||<T : BooleanType>(lhs: T, @autoclosure rhs: () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

probably your 'hack' using a `{ $0 || $1 }` is the best solutions here.

Comment: It looks like the only reason for the second one is that the first one cannot be `@_transparent` due to a bug. The craziest thing is that their implementations are identical.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of Swifts closure semantics. It takes your arguments and applies function to them, omitting argument names.

```
protocol Numeric {
    ...
    public static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    ...
}
```

In example with Ints, you would pass (Int, Int) into a closure, and + function in Numeric protocol expects exactly two ints to sum them.

Thats why code like below works just fine

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(0, +)
```

Because you just took 2 ints, and applied function, which takes just two ints.
If you write your own function, which would take just two argument, it would work as well.

```
func myOwnAwesomeFunc<T: Numeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T { in
    return 1 // production ready
}

[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(0, myOwnAwesomeFunc) // prints 1
```

Good so far. But why can't we write

```
[true, false, true].reduce(false, ||) // yields Cannot invoke 'reduce' 
// with an argument list of type 
// '(Bool, (Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool)'
```

That's because this operator takes bool and a closure, which returns bool. **Not bool, closure!**
But if it is like this, why aren't we writing `true || { false }()` ?
Thats because of @autoclosure, which takes care of curly braces for us.

Main question, why is it implemented this way, so we can't use Swifts awesome short-hand closure syntax with booleans? Idk

Comment: It's written this way to allow `||` to short-circuit and avoid evaluating the RHV if the LHV is `true`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Would like it to work in a more expected way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, I modified the reduceBools function to take the operator as a parameter -

```
typealias LogicalOperator = ((Bool, @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool)

func reduceBools(values: [Bool], combine: LogicalOperator) -> Bool {
    var started: Bool = false
    return values.reduce(into: true, { (result, value) in
        result = started ? try! combine(result, value) : value // obviously up to you how you'd handle the try/catch
        started = true
    })
}

let bools = [true, false, false, true]

let result1 = self.reduceBools(values: bools, combine: ||)
print(result1) // prints true

let result2 = self.reduceBools(values: bools, combine: &&)
print(result2) // prints false
```

Or it could be more useful as an extension of Sequence -

```
extension Sequence where Element == Bool {

    func reduce(_ combine: LogicalOperator) -> Bool {
        var started: Bool = false
        return self.reduce(into: true, { (result, value) in
            result = started ? try! combine(result, value) : value
            started = true
        })
    }
}

print(bools.reduce(||)) // prints true
```