# Ambiguous reference to member &&

Tags: swift, type-inference, reduce

If I wish to calculate if all `Bool`s in the list are `true` with this snippet, why won't the types be correctly inferred?

```
let bools = [false, true, false, true]
let result = bools.reduce(true, combine: &&)
```

Comment: I suggest you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34699637/5654848). It is explained in detail.

Comment: You can simply write this as `let result = !bools.contains(false)`, which will compile with ambiguity btw :) But definitely interested in exactly why this is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same bug a while ago (but then with `||`). If you want to use `reduce` for this, the easiest solution is to write

```
let result = bools.reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1 })
```

or

```
let result = bools.reduce(true) { $0 && $1 }
```

instead. As pointed out in the comments, you can also use

```
let result = !bools.contains(false)
```

Not only is this more readable, but it's also more efficient because it will stop at the first encounter of `false` rather than iterating over the entire array (though the compiler might optimize this).