# What aren't these two ways of expressing map function equivalent?

Tags: swift, map-function

I got a surprise today while looking at another SO question:

```
let s = "1,a"
let arr = s.split(separator: ",")
let result = arr.compactMap{Int($0)} // ok
let result2 = arr.compactMap(Int.init) // error
```

Why is line 3 legal but line 4 is not? I would have thought these two ways of saying "coerce the incoming parameter to Int if possible" would be completely equivalent.

I understand that line 4 is choking on the Subsequence, and I see how to get out of the difficulty:

```
let result2 = arr.map(String.init).compactMap(Int.init) // ok
```

What I don't understand is why they *both* don't choke in the same way.

Comment: Does `.init` actually init?

Comment: @aheze `Int(...)` _is_ `Int.init`. One is a call, the other is the name. With parentheses we are providing the name of a function and that's what I'm doing. The question is, why isn't this exactly the same function I was using in the curly brace. As I say, I can twiddle line 4 to make it work, I just don't understand why I have to.

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that `split` returns a `[Substring]`, but `Int.init` wants a `String`. This, for example, works: `arr.map(String.init).compactMap(Int.init)`. I'm curious why `Int($0)` works to begin with

Comment: @NewDev Yeah, I know, and that’s the question.

Comment: @matt, didn't notice your edit before commenting :)

Comment: The two answers demonstrate why. There are two places I find that I frequently can’t use `.init` when I want to because overloads are missing. Default arguments are one, which you’re running up against here. The other is autoclosures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699576/use-logical-operator-as-combine-closure-in-reduce

Comment: @Jessy I still find it weird linguistically that `Int()` is not itself identically syntactic sugar for `Int.init`. I guess it’s because the logic and syntax of function references is different; it has to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `Int.init` overload that accepts a `Substring` has the following signature:

```
public init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S : StringProtocol
```

So, `Int($0)` works because it uses the default `radix`, but there isn't an `Int.init(_:)` that accepts a `Substring` - there's only `Int.init(_:radix:)` that does - and so it fails.

But if there was one:

```
extension Int {
    public init?<S>(_ text: S) where S : StringProtocol {
        self.init(text, radix: 10)
    }
}
```

then this would work:

```
let result1 = arr.compactMap(Int.init)
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact the first version (`Int($0)`) calls this initializer, which has two parameters (one of them has a default value):

```
@inlinable public init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S : StringProtocol
```

If I define a custom initializer like so, then the second example works too.

```
extension Int {
    init?<S>(_ string: S) where S: StringProtocol {
        // convert somehow, e.g: self.init(string, radix: 10)
        return nil
    }
}

let result2 = arr.compactMap(Int.init)
```

*It seems to me that if I write `Int.init` in the `compactMap`, it can call only the exact initializer (or function), and the second parameter of the first called initializer cannot be inferred.*

Another example:

```
func test1<S>(param1: S) -> String where S: StringProtocol {
    return ""
}

func test2<S>(param1: S, defaultParam: String = "") -> String where S: StringProtocol {
    return ""
}

extension Sequence {
    func customCompactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) -> ElementOfResult?) -> [ElementOfResult] {
        compactMap(transform)
    }
}

arr.customCompactMap(test1)
arr.customCompactMap(test2) // error
```

I think the function references cannot hold any default values. Unfortunately I didn't find any official reference to this, but seems interesting.

Proof, last example:

```
func test3(param1: String, defaultParam: String = "") { }
let functionReference = test3
functionReference("", "")
functionReference("") // error
```

Here the `functionReference's` type is `(String, String) -> ()`, even though the `test3` function has a default value for the second parameter. As you can see `functionReference` cannot be called with only one value.

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking for the Swift forum post where someone on the core team explained this, but sorry, I couldn't find it. You can go asking there and get clarification on this point:

**Default arguments don't actually produce overloads.**

Instead, using default arguments at call site is syntactic sugar for using all arguments. The compiler inserts the defaults for the ones you don't use.

### A few results of that…

---

You cannot use functions with default arguments as closures with simplified signatures. You have to wrap them in new closures, as you demonstrated in your question.

```swift
func ƒ(_: Int = 0) { }

let intToVoid: (Int) -> Void = ƒ // compiles

// Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> ()' to specified type '() -> Void'
let voidToVoid: () -> Void = ƒ
```

---

Methods with different default argument patterns, that look the same at call site, are not considered overrides.

```swift
class Base {
  func ƒ(_: Any? = nil) -> String { "Base" }
}

final class Derived: Base {
  // No `override` required.
  func ƒ() -> String { "Derived" }
}

Base().ƒ() // "Base"
Derived().ƒ() // "Derived"
(Derived().ƒ as (Any?) -> String)("argument") // "Base"
```

---

Default arguments do not allow for satisfaction of protocol requirements.

```swift
protocol Protocol {
  func ƒ() -> String
}

// Type 'Base' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol'
extension Base: Protocol { }
```